# Writing LLVM source files vs. using APIs

Tags: llvm

I am creating an LLVM backend for a compiler. I am wondering if there is any downside to having my backend write IR code in files instead of using the APIs. The APIs are complicated (especially if one is using a language other than C++, in my case Haskell) and hard to use. The IR is much easier to understand. I don't need JIT compilation, the output code will be compiled to machine code by the standard command line tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IR format changes from version to version. API changes much less frequently. There were examples in the past when IR format changed dramatically, so you'd need to invest big amount of time to tolerate these changes.

Using API is the preferable method. If sometimes it's not clear for you which API calls you will need - you can use cpp backend as a source of inspiration :)

Answer (score 2):

As Anton said, there's a definite advantage in using the API as opposed to spitting out textual IR. I just want to address the point you raise regarding the complexity of the API and its usage from Haskell.

Note that LLVM has a C API, which (apart from being more stable) is suitable for foreign language interfaces. Python bindings exist for LLVM using this API, as well as Haskell bindings ([this is easily found](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/llvm-3.0.0.0) by Google) and for other languages as well.

Comment: I am definitely aware of the Haskell bindings.. But they are restrictive (they don't allow for dynamic number of function arguments, not known at compile time of the Haskell program). I also honestly find the API ugly and not intuitive.

Comment: @aelguindy: well, your mileage may vary :-) Keep in mind that writing IR is also untrivial, because it's a sophisticated language. I.e. you have to keep track of all register names on your own - the API does it for you.